# How to execute or call a function from another dart file

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a dart file with IndexedStack and the following function in the same file to change the stacks.

The file with method as follows-

```
  class RootApp extends StatefulWidget  with selectedTab {
  @override
  _RootAppState createState() => _RootAppState();
}


class _RootAppState extends State<RootApp> {
  int pageIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> pages = [
    ......
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ....

    return AnimatedBottomNavigationBar(
      .......
      onTap: (index) {
        selectedTab(index);
      },
    );
  }

  selectedTab(index) {
    setState(() {
      pageIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

The other file is as follows---

```
class CreatBudgetPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CreatBudgetPageState createState() => _CreatBudgetPageState();
}

class _CreatBudgetPageState extends State<CreatBudgetPage> {
  .......
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('expenses/' + userId + '/' + todayDate)
        .add({
   ....
    }).then((_) {
      print("collection created");
      void rootApp() => selectedTab(0);
    }).catchError((error) {
      print(error);
    });
  }
```

How can i call this function from another dart file?

Edit: I tried the methods suggested by Rohith but they aren't working. So i have updated my dart file.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the file in which your function is in for example

```
import "IndexedTabs.dart";

void main() => selectedTab(index)
```

or you can use `mixin` like this

```
mixin SelectedTab {
  selectedTab(index) {
     setState(() {
        pageIndex = index;
      });
  }
}
```

In main file

```
class Main with selectedTab {
  void main() => selectedTab(index);
}
```

**Update**

This is in your main file

```
class RootApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RootAppState createState() => _RootAppState();
}


class RootApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RootAppState createState() => _RootAppState();
}


class _RootAppState extends State<RootApp> {
  int pageIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> pages = [
    
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      items: [],
      onTap: (index) {
        setState(() {
          selectedTab(pageIndex, index);
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is the file with your function

```
void selectedTab(pageIndex, index) {
  pageIndex = index;
}
```

Comment: That entire code is in one file. The other file is differrent and edited again.

Comment: Can you please review?

Comment: I am currently busy, I will look after some time

Comment: Just curious, you want to use the ‘selectedTab()’ from the first file in the second file?

Comment: From the second file. I want the page to go back to the first tab in the Indexed stack abter i submit a form. Thanks for your time brother.

Answer (score 1):

just import the file then you can freely call any function or class in that file :

```
import 'yourfile.dart'

yourmethode();
```